# Use https / ssl with here.com maps api

Tags: here-api

So what's the real story with using https/ssl connections with the here.com maps api?  As of 2015?  I know they have changed a lot over the last year or two.  I've read some older 2012/2013 posts where they say you must have enterprise.

Can it be done or is the paid Enterprise Account a requirement if you want https connections?

I currently have a 'Free Consumer Account' and am having difficulties pulling up maps via https.  So, not sure if it is my account type or bugs in code that need to be worked out.

Answer (score 1):

- The new **HERE Maps API 3.0** supports `https` for all users - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27556648/how-to-call-here-maps-api-v3-using-https/27561585#27561585)
- The older **HERE Maps API 2.5.x for Enterprise** supported `https` for paying customers only
- The older Basic **HERE Maps API 2.5.x** was free and did not support `https`