# HERE Maps script contains unsecure (mixed content) http calls

Tags: javascript, here-api

We have our site served over https, and have the HERE maps api included in some of our pages. We are currently getting Mixed content errors from this api, as I can see it is trying to load images over a xmlhttpRequest.  The Map API is currently just showing a blank window, with no map information.

We are using the latest 3.0 version available (Which right now is 3.0.16.0).

Also to note, I have tried the "useHttps = true" solution in this answer: [How to call HERE Maps API v3 using HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27556648/how-to-call-here-maps-api-v3-using-https).  As well the documentation seems different from the time that this answer was posted so I cannot look into this rule in the current documentation.

here is the related error, with the filename containing the conflicting xmlHttpRequest: [Error Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KDFm.png).

Answer (score 0):

Make that you are configuring `H.service.Platform` with the following options:

```
const platform = new H.service.Platform({
  app_id: '{{your_app_id}}',
  app_code: '{{your_app_code}}',
  useHTTPS: true,
  useCIT: true
});
```

It seems you had the wrong capitalization of `useHTTPS`, or were missing the `useCIT` property. With the above, your map should load the tiles over HTTPS.

**[SEE DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/here-basemap-highres)**